# how to set a paintdrawable as view background?

Tags: drawable, paint

I'm trying to set a PaintDrawable as a background for a view in order to change the color dynamically and keep the borders but when i write :

```
vi.setBackground(pd);`
```

i got an error : NoSuchMethodError
here is my code :

```
PaintDrawable pd = new PaintDrawable(color);

pd.setCornerRadius(4);
pd.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
vi.setBackground(pd)                         
DyL.addView(vi);
```

Answer (score 0):

`setBackground(Drawable)` was introduced in Android SDK 16. If you want compatibility with earlier SDKs you should use the deprecated setBackgroundDrawable or explicitly test the SDK version.